# How to display an image using a different filename than the physical filename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my image hosting webapp I created a hackish way for image de-duplication to save on storage space by having an image.rb model with paperclip to store physical images and a second model imagelink.rb to store image names which link to the physical image. So in my imagelink model I use "belongs_to: image" and add an index on the imagelink to image_id of the image. The naming of the image and imagelink is simply an encoded version of the ActiveRecord ID.

When uploading the image I simply check it's md5sum to see if the image already exists if it does exist then I create a new imagelink ID and use the image ID of the original image. Otherwise I save the image and create a new image ID. This allows me to have a physical image like "vb56.jpg" and an encoded imagelink like "vb56.jpg" as well as a second imagelink like "4gb7.jpg" which also uses the physical image "vb56.jpg"

So naturally now I want to display the original physical image "vb56.jpg" but using the name "4gb7.jpg" when being accessed from the "4gb7.jpg" imagelink. I can achieve this by making another request for each imagelink which would look something like this:

```
images_controller.rb
before_action :set_image, only: [:show, :show_direct]

def show_direct
  path = @image.image.image.url
  url = Rails.root.join('uploads' + path)
  send_file url, type: @image.image.image_content_type, disposition: 'inline'
end

def set_image
  @image = ImageLink.decode(params[:id])
  raise 'image not found' if @image.nil?
end


image_view.html.erb
<%
  id = @image.encoded_id
  ext = @image.image.extension
%>
<img src="<%= MYAPP::DOMAIN %><%= id %>.<%= ext %>" class="image-display" />
```

So two problems doing it this way is 1) This is probably going to create slowness as well as tons of requests to the rails server for each image displayed on a page. 2) This is messing up the way I store session[:previous_url] for logging in with devise which is "session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath" since each image is a request it's storing the last requested image as the previous_url instead of the actual page the user is on.

Is there a way I can display the image without making tons of requests like currently doing? Doing the proper way with <%= image_tag(@image.image.image.url) %> to display the physical image will show the image as the original filename but I'd like it to show the filename as the imagelink name so that to the user the physical image name will always match the imagelink name.

Also am I doing session[:previous_url] wrong? Is there a better way to do it to capture the page URL rather than the URL of other requests coming from within the page?

Comment: Are you using `carrierwave` or `paperclip`? Carrierwave has a built-in feature that allows you to randomize the name of each photo upload so that each photo is different even if they are named the same on your end.

Comment: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files

Comment: I would simplify and just store a url to the image in your `images` table. You are just adding a layer of complexity and getting rid of the join will help performance.


As you grow you will most likely need to use a CDN like S3 anyways and using rails as a router to serve static assets is not going to scale well. I would also use just use a fast hashing algorithm to generate the file names as your current solution could lead to race conditions and [pigeonhole problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: @miler350 - I am using paperclip. But the issue is not having two images with the same name as the images will always be saved with a unique encoded ID. I was trying to create fake images so to speak so that I could save storage space by using multiple image links that all point to the same image if it was the same image that was uploaded.

Comment: @max - Just to make sure I'm reading right, you are saying trying to de-duplicate images is not worth it? I should get rid of the imagelink model and just allow saving multiple images even if they are the same image? I guess that would make things a lot easier but seems like it would potentially use up GBs of storage for the same image.